# Colocar input radio disable

Tags: php, jquery

Tabela dentro do `While` para criar a tabela com `inputs radio` dinâmico:

```
$y = 0;
while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos)) {   
$tabela1 .= '<tr>';
$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="text" readonly="true" size="20" name= "Produto['.$y.']" class= "Produto" value="'.$rows_cursos['Descricao'].'"></td>';
$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="radio" name= "Sim['.$y.']" value="Ok" required></td>';
$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="radio" name= "Sim['.$y.']" value="Não Ok" required></td>'
$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="radio" name= "DataP['.$y.']" value="Ok" required></td>';
$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="radio" name= "DataP['.$y.']" value="Não Ok" required></td>';
$tabela1 .= '<td> <textarea type="text" class= "Observacao" name="Observacao['.$y.']" rows="2" cols="30"></textarea></td>';
$tabela1 .= '</tr>'; 
$y++;
}
```

Mostro na imagem a tabela montada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pretendia que nas linhas onde retorna os produtos rodeados a vermelho bloqueasse os `inputs radio` também rodeados a vermelho, para não ser obrigatório preencher.

Comment: Qual é a condição para identificar os registros destacados? E você precisa bloquear ou deixar opcional?

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss, preciso mesmo de bloquear. A condição é, as linhas com os  seguintes produtos(x,x,x,x,x), bloqueia os input radio com o name=DataP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar um operador ternário preenchendo uma string com o valor `required` por padrão, mas com o valor `disabled` quando os campos forem os que você quer desabilitar.

```
$y = 0;
while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos)) {   

$property = ($rows_cursos ["Descricao"]==="x" || $rows_cursos ["Descricao"]==="x2")? "disabled" : "required";

$tabela1 .= '<tr>';
$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="text" readonly="true" size="20" name= "Produto['.$y.']" class= "Produto" value="'.$rows_cursos['Descricao'].'"></td>';
$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="radio" name= "Sim['.$y.']" value="Ok" required></td>';
$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="radio" name= "Sim['.$y.']" value="Não Ok" required></td>'
$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="radio" name= "DataP['.$y.']" value="Ok" '.$property.'></td>';
$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="radio" name= "DataP['.$y.']" value="Não Ok" '.$property.'></td>';
$tabela1 .= '<td> <textarea type="text" class= "Observacao" name="Observacao['.$y.']" rows="2" cols="30"></textarea></td>';
$tabela1 .= '</tr>'; 
$y++;
}
```

Talvez você possa trocar o campo `$rows_cursos["Descricao"]` por algo como `$rows_cursos["Id"]`, mas como não sei a estrutura coloquei `$rows_cursos["Descricao"]` mesmo.